# Leading error in Text box in InDesign, do you know of a way to fix it?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, cs5

I am creating this text box in InDesign CS5 and on the last row of a paragraph I get a bigger leading for no reason. If I select the text and check the leading setting it is the same for all rows in the text box but it just doesnt look right... it happend to me multiple times... and I don't know how to get rid of it... even if I write a diffrent text the error leading still remains... annoying bug...

Do you know of a way to fix it ?

Have a look at the picture to understand what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go under Preferences → Type and click the box next to "Apply Leading to Entire Paragraphs."

Then select every last character of your text and make everything the SAME leading, and use the "space before" or "space after" settings in the paragraph style to add your extra space. NEVER change the leading of one line randomly to add space between paragraphs. If later on you have to change the size or the leading of the type, or both, some words will have different leading than others, plus you'll have to reset it manually for every paragraph. Space Before is there for a reason. Use it.

Comment: AHA!! I knew I was doing it wrong :) Space Before&After in the paragraph style is what I should of been using for doing that...just didn't knew about it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that the paragraph return has the same larger leading as the heading above it. Triple-click into the paragraph to select the entire paragraph and set its leading to be what you want for the text.

Comment: good answer also. thx

Answer (score 0):

Aaaahhh... sorry, just figured it out.... can I delete/close my silly question now ? :D

**What I did to fix it... I selected the whole text area, I set the same leading for all rows and then again I set diffrent leading for the rows I wanted to have a bigger/smaler leading...**

But if I get errors like that sometimes... probably I am using/doing something wrong... or maybe its just a bug...

But if there is someone who can explain more on the issue, like some advice when working with a lot of text, youre welcome :)

Comment: asking a question on GD and then answering it yourself 2 min later... its like talking to yourself out loud in the bus :P

Comment: But it is okay to answer your own questions. Also, it is okay to talk to yourself as long as you don't answer back. Oh, wait... ;-)

Comment: Advice when working w/ lots of text --- use styles, paragraph, then character, and only allow / apply local formatting when _absolutely_ necessary.